# Fancybox 2 - SWF Background Color Not Working

Tags: flash, fancybox-2

I just updated to Fancybox 2 and my flash animations no longer have background colors. This was the code I was using for Fancybox 1, which no longer works.

```
    $("#myFlashFile").fancybox({
    'width' : '650',
    'height' : '620',
    'autoScale' : false,
    'transitionIn' : 'fade',
    'transitionOut' : 'fade',
    'speedIn' : 800, 
    'speedOut' :    200,                
    'type' : 'swf',
    'wmode' : 'opaque',
    'swf' : {bgcolor:'#ffcc00'},
    'overlayShow' : true,
    });
```

The line that called the background color in Fancybox 1 was:

```
'swf' : {bgcolor:'#ffcc00'}
```

**Edit**
I replaced 'swf' : {bgcolor:'#ffcc00'}, with

```
        'beforeShow': function(){
            $(".fancybox-skin").css("backgroundColor","#ffcc00");
                }
```

and it works now. The final code looks like:

```
        $("#myFlashFile").fancybox({
    'padding'   :   6,          
    'width' : '650',
    'height' : '620',
    'autoScale' : false,
    'openEffect': 'fade',
    'prevEffect': 'fade',
    'nextEffect': 'fade',
    'openSpeed'   : 300,
    'closeSpeed'   : 200,       
    'type' : 'swf',
    'wmode' : 'opaque',
    'beforeShow': function(){
            $(".fancybox-skin").css("backgroundColor","#ffcc00");
                }       
     });
```

Comment: Fancybox 2 options are new and not compatible with previous versions. Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the correct options of the version you are using. On the other hand, do you mean the background color inside fancybox container?

Comment: The only values it shows for swf files is: wmode: 'transparent', allowfullscreen   : 'true', allowscriptaccess : 'always'. If it was a flash file on a webpage, I would use: <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffcc00">, hence the old code using bgcolor. I have no idea why I can't pass flash parameters anymore. Changing the background color inside the container might work, assuming I can only change it for "#myFlashFile".

Comment: I ended up using beforeShow to change the background color for #myFlasFile. I've made the edits to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same issue, so I just changed the default in the `jquery.fancybox.js` file.
From:

```
swf : {
    wmode: 'transparent',
    allowfullscreen   : 'true',
    allowscriptaccess : 'always'
},
```

To:

```
swf : {
    wmode: 'opaque',
    allowfullscreen   : 'true',
    allowscriptaccess : 'always'
},
```

Worked like a charm!